# Torus coordinates and triple integration

Tags: integration, coordinate-systems

Torus coordinates are given by
$$x=(R+r \cos\theta)\cos\phi,\space y=(R+r \cos\theta)\sin\phi,\space z=r\sin\theta,$$
with $R>0$.

A given torus $T_b$ is defined by
$$T_b=\{(r,\theta,\phi):0\leq r\leq b<R, 0\leq\theta\leq 2\pi,0\leq\phi\leq 2\pi\}.$$
Is it correct that the volume is given by
$$\int_0^b\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}1 Id\phi d\theta dr$$
where $I$ is the integrationfactor of the torus coordinates? How do I find $I$?

P.S. Is there an easy way to sketch this torus in cartesian coordinates?

Comment: You need to take the absolute value of the Jacobian matrix.

Comment: But the rest is correct?

Comment: The $z$ coordinate relationship was incorrect.  I edited.

Comment: Yeah youre right, and do you perhaps know an easy way to sketch the torus in cartesian coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

Let's parametrize the torus (parametrize the volume in space). We can parametrize a circumference in the $y=0$ plane, with radius $r$, centered in the point $(R,0,0)$ by $$\alpha(u,v) = (R + u\cos v, 0, R+ u \sin v), \quad 0  < u < r, \quad 0 < v < 2\pi,$$ and rotating around the $z$ axis we have: $${\bf x}(u,v,w) = ((R+u\cos v)\cos w, (R+u \cos v)\sin w, R+u\sin v),$$ with $0 < w < 2\pi$. The oriented of the torus is: $$V = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^r |\det({\bf x}_u,{\bf x}_v,{\bf x}_w)|\,{\rm d}u\,{\rm d}v\,{\rm d}w.$$

I don't think there is an easy way to look at this using cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Does the determinant of the Jacobian matrix not need an absolute value sign?  Or is the orientation here such that the determinant is already positive?

Comment: And what is the determinant of the Jacobian?

Comment: I got (in my notation) $|-(rR+r^2\cos\theta)|$, you too?

Comment: @TonyStrong Do you know how to find the determinant of a matrix?

Comment: That's why I said "oriented" volume... Just in the same way that taking the determinant of two vectors in $\Bbb R^2$ to find the area of the parallelogram spanned may yield a negative number... well, I'm not sure that it's worth worrying about, I'll just edit the absolute values in.

Comment: @Dr.MV See my comment above :)

Comment: You just need to compute the derivatives ${\bf x}_u$, etc, put these vectors in the rows (or columns, your choice) of a matrix, and compute the determinant.

Comment: The result is $r(R+r \cos \theta)$ ... that is with the $+$ sign.

Comment: Yes, thanks! Thats what I got

Comment: And is there an easy way of sketching this torus in cartesian coordinates?

Comment: It is just your usual torus (the surface), with the insides filled in. You get a volume in $\Bbb R^3$. If you can sketch a torus, you can sketch this.

Comment: But what is the height of the torus?

Comment: Do you know how to parametrize a surface of revolution? The torus as it is written in your question is the revolution of the circle in the plane $y=0$, centered in $(R,0,0)$ with radius $r$. You can draw that. If you are having too much trouble seeing it, make $R=2$, $r=1$ and try plotting it [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/).