# Torus integration question

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, complex-analysis

We have a torus whose "circle" has radius of $a$. We need to find the volume of this torus.

So what we did was that we put it into polar coordinates:

$$(x,y,z) = (a \cos(\phi), a \sin(\phi), 0) + (r \cos(\theta) \cos(\phi), r \cos(\theta) \sin(\phi), r \sin(\theta)) = ((a + r \cos(\theta) ) \cos(\phi), (a + r \cos(\theta))\sin(\phi),r \sin(\theta))$$

Where the parameters are: $0 \leq \phi \leq 2\pi$

$ 0 \leq \theta < 2\pi $

$0 \leq r \leq b$

However I don't understand how we chosen new coordinates for $(x,y,z)$ and how we got those parameters to integrate on.

My question is similar to: [Torus coordinates and triple integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1268760/torus-coordinates-and-triple-integration)

However I would need more explanation on it.

Comment: $a$ is radius of torus from center of the torus to the center of the torus tube. Center of the torus is $(0, 0, 0)$ and the circle lies in xy-plane. So, $(a \cos\phi, a\sin\phi, 0)$ is the center of the torus cross sections at angle $\phi$ from positive x-axis. . The next term is the equation of the cross-sections which are circles at any given $\phi$ with radius of the torus tube being  $b$.

Comment: @MathLover I am just curious why can't we do it the following way: 

i) We get the surface of the circle in the tube. 

ii) We get the perimeter of the outside circle (that forms a torus as the circle of the tube).

iii) We multiply the area of the circle in the tube with the perimeter of the outside circle.

Comment: Sorry I did not get you. Are you trying to find the volume?

Comment: @MathLover Yes, the volume. What I was trying to say is: That we would get a perimiter/circumference of a circle, so like $2 \pi r$. Then we would multiply it by the area of the circle that would be in the tube of the torus.

Comment: @MathLover So we would get: $2\pi r_1 \cdot \pi r_2^2  $

Comment: @MathLover Where $r_1$ would be the distance from the center of the torus, to the center of the tube. And r_2 would be the distance from the tube to the center of the tube.

Comment: yes that is the correct formula for volume of torus.

Comment: and how you are thinking about it is also correct

Comment: @MathLover So it is alot easier than triple integration...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define the radius $r$ as that of the cross section of the torus and $R$ as the radius of the donut to the center of that circle. I suggest that you use Pappus's ($2^{nd}$) Centroid Theorem: the volume of a planar area of revolution is the product of the area $A$ and the length of the path traced by its centroid $R$, i.e., $2\pi R$. The bottom line is that the volume is given simply by $V=2\pi RA$. Obliviously, the area of the cross section is $A=\pi r^2$, so the volume of the torus is $V=2\pi^2Rr^2$. And while we're here, Pappus's ($1^{st}$) Centroid Theorem: the surface area of a planar area of revolution is the product of the circumference $C$ and the length of the path traced by its centroid $R$, thus, $S=2\pi RC$. For the torus $C=2\pi r$, and thus $S=4\pi^2 Rr$.